# I want to generate random numbers within given range in java

Tags: java, function, random

For that, I got the solution but I can't understand it:
I have used below function to generate random numbers within the given range but what is the meaning of below function?

```
static int randomRangeInNumber(int min, int max) {
    Random r=new Random();
    return r.nextInt((max-min)+1)+min;
}
```

What i have returned i didnt get
Please help making me understand its meaning
any help will be appreciated

Comment: Which part do you not understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> nextInt is normally exclusive of the top value, so add 1 to make it
>   inclusive

So, in your case, we'll say the `max` is 10 and `min` is 5.

`nextInt(n)` will give you a random number between 0 and n - 1.

So adding the `+1` will let you include the value of `n`.

`nextInt(max-min)` therefore gives you a random number between (in this case) 0 and 5 - 1 (and include the 5 because of the +1)

Then adding the `min` again, means it will give you the above random number, but add 5 to it, so the result will be a random number between 5 and 10.

Comment: Thanks sir ,I understood it now

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [nextInt(int bound)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) says

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence.

So your `nextInt` call is

1. taking the return value, which is in the range [0..bound] (where the bound is `(max-min)+1`) and then
2. scaling it into the range [min..max] with `+min`.

```
return r.nextInt((max-min)+1)+min;
       \__________1_________/\_2_/
```